# Cannot deploy my updates to cloudfoundry

Tags: deployment, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, cloud-foundry

I have a simple app running on tomcat (using Postgresql). I deployed it to the Cloud-Foundry using the STS plugin and it runs OK. Recently I've encountered serious compilation problems (related to JS and JQuery) which led me to re install my STS. 
Now, when I run the app locally it runs perfect but when I use "Update & Restart" nothing happens - my new updates are not deployed! (I'm connected and Start/Stop works). I don't have a clue for how to tackle this. Please help.

Comment: Lately I have been having this problem with grails so what I've been doing is stopping the server, doing a push and then starting it again. Basically a manual update.

Comment: Do you mean push via the command line console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have reinstalled your STS, I would suggest you delete your app from Cloud Foundry and deploy your project from STS again. It might be because your project is not being linked with the app you have on cloudfoundry.com

Try that and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Well it worked at the 1st time but now the problem returned. for some reason I cannot update my code at the cloud (both java and jsp files). Can it be related to the packaging stage? maven?